# scrlayer-scrpage: "Part No." in header

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I would like to have "Part 1", "Part 2" etc. in the lehead and the chapter title in the rohead. Getting the chapter title where I want it is no problem, neither is getting the word "Part". However, I have no idea how to get the part number into the header.

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright, headsepline, chapterpefix=true]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\lehead{\partname}
\rohead{\leftmark}

\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\part{}
\chapter{The First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\part{}
\chapter{The Second Chapter}
\lipsum[11-30]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean `\lehead{\partname~\thepart}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, that did it, thank you! (I was closer to the solution than I thought).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `\automark[chapter]{part}` and redefine `\partmarkformat`. Then `\part` cleans automatically the chapter entry in header. Additionally there is no part entry in header if there are some pages (TOC, Introductino etc.) before the first part.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside, openright, headsepline, chapterpefix=true]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{part}% <- added
\renewcommand*{\partmarkformat}{\partname~\thepart}% <- added
\clearpairofpagestyles

\lehead{\leftmark}% <- changed
\rohead{\rightmark}% <- changed

\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\addchap{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]
\part{}
\chapter{The First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\part{}
\chapter{The Second Chapter}
\lipsum[11-30]
\part{}
Part not followed by a chapter
\lipsum[31-50]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the parts have no names just invent some and use the number

```
\lehead{Part \thepart}
```

Or is that not what you want?

Comment: I would recommend the solution in Ulrike's comment (``\lehead{\partname~\thepart}``) instead, since it's more flexible (e.g. in combination with ``babel`` etc).

Comment: I agree but since the \part{} is empty you will only get the number. Maybe if you define \part[Part]{} will give you the output you would like to have.

Comment: No, that's what ``\partname`` is for..

Comment: Ah my mistake I should have read it correctly :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per Ulrike Fischer's comment, it's `\lehead{\partname~\thepart}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright, headsepline, chapterpefix=true]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\lehead{\partname~\thepart}
\rohead{\leftmark}

\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\part{}
\chapter{The First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\part{}
\chapter{The Second Chapter}
\lipsum[11-30]
\end{document}
```